# Root-NFS: Server returned error -5 while mounting rootfs

Tags: linux-kernel, nfs, u-boot

I'm try to load embedded linux on my device.

Kernel command line:

```
setenv bootcmd 'nfs 10.0.0.1:/home/master/rootfs3/boot/uImage;bootm;'
setenv bootargs console=ttyTX0,57600n8 root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=10.0.0.1:/home/master/rootfs3 ip=dhcp init=/sbin/init
```

System loading fails:

```
VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 1 part 10 variant 9 rev 1
rtc-lpc32xx rtc-lpc32xx: setting system clock to 1970-01-06 00:47:10 UTC (434830)
Sending DHCP requests .., OK
IP-Config: Got DHCP answer from 0.0.0.0, my address is 10.0.0.10
IP-Config: Complete:
     device=eth0, addr=10.0.0.10, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=10.0.0.1,
     host=10.0.0.10, domain=, nis-domain=(none),
     bootserver=0.0.0.0, rootserver=10.0.0.1, rootpath=
Waiting 4sec before mounting root device...
Looking up port of RPC 100005/1 on 10.0.0.1
Root-NFS: Unable to get mountd port number from server, using default
Root-NFS: Server returned error -5 while mounting /home/master/rootfs2
VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS, trying floppy.
VFS: Cannot open root device "nfs" or unknown-block(2,0)
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
1f00        768 mtdblock0 (driver?)
1f01       2048 mtdblock1 (driver?)
1f02       2048 mtdblock2 (driver?)
1f03      15360 mtdblock3 (driver?)
1f04      87040 mtdblock4 (driver?)
1f05      23808 mtdblock5 (driver?)
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)
```

`Server returned error -5` - what does it mean and where can I know about this error?

Comment: ok, I find that `error-5` means `NFSERR_IO` (look at `include/linux/nfs.h`). Also this could be a disk error (look at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1094.txt). But how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

1.Disable the firewall
On my Fedora 18
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld

2.Disable selinux
vi /etc/selinux/config

-- Comment SELINUX=enforcing
-- Add #SELINUX=disabled

restart your linux.